# How to schedule a task at accurate time on Jailbroken iPhone in deep sleep

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, daemon, jailbreak

I'm developing an background (daemon) application that will schedule a task on an exact time. For example, do something at 3 PM, or it can be do something after 3 hours. I've tried NSTimer and scheduling NSThread, but it does not do the task at the time I schedule because iPhone is in deep sleep.

Note that this is an application on a jail-broken device and run as a daemon, so it doesn't have `UIApplication` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my daemon. I couldn't find any working method for scheduling device wakes. Instead I prevent it from ever falling in a deep sleep by infinitely playing audio file with silence. That way you don't need [IOKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html) to cancel sleep and your device will stay awake. I can't find the code now but it's very simple - a few calls to AVAudioPlayer. You also need to setup audio session for audio playing and mixing. It's all public and very well known APIs so there shouldn't be any problems implementing that.

There are problems with it. For example, playing audio file will reroute audio to the device receiver. By default audio is playing through the speaker so you need to take care of that. You also need to detect when the screen is turned on/off because device will not sleep when the screen is turned on. When the screen is turned off you start playing silence. When it's turned on you stop it. That will also solve mixing problems with other apps that are trying to play audio.

Unfortunately I don't have any code with me right now to show you some examples. I can add the code later if need it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This approach seems to prevent the device to be sleep. However, I would like to find out the approach that allow the device to go to sleep mode, but still allow my application to perform the task at the accurate time.